# Why is `self` needed inside this instance method?

Tags: ruby, self

Going through Well Grounded Rubyist.

```
class Car
  @@cars = {}
  attr_reader :make
  def make_mates
    @@cars[self.make]
  end
  ...
end
```

Why do we need `self` in the `make_mates` instance method? When I run the code without `self`, it works the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need it in that case.

You only need to refer to an attribute with `self` if you're assigning to it, to distinguish it from assigning to a local.

Comment: Thanks @dave Do you have any idea why author might used it?

Comment: Sometimes people do unnecessary things like in code because they know they're needed in some cases but they're not sure if they're needed in the case at hand.

Comment: Hmm, interesting... Will keep this in mind! Thanks again @dave.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth Also, the code may have been copied from a context that did require it, but the author neglected to remove the redundant `self.` simply because *it worked*.  Done that myself a few dozen times.  :D

Comment: Some developers also prefer it for clarity, especially in long methods. In short methods like this one it's obvious that it's not a local variable, but in longer methods it's harder to determine at a glance. Of course, this is another argument in favor of shorter methods!